# Sending explicit Intent to my Activity declared in my Android lib

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a ADT app, myadtapp (myapppkg), uses an Android Lib, myadtlib (mylibpackage). Inside myadtlib project, I created a custom Activity, myjavapkg.MyActivity, and declare the Activity in MyAdtLib::AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mylibpackage" ... >
    ... 
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name="myjavapkg.MyActivity"
            android:exported="true" />        
    ...
```

I am surprised the following code doesn't work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("mylibpackage", MyActivity.class.getName());
startActivity(intent);
```

The error is:

```
ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {mylibpackage/myjavapkg.MyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

If I move MyActivity declartion to the myadtapp manifest file, it would work, but I don't want to.  What is wrong with the above using an MyActivity in an my Android lib?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: nope. The same error but showing the wrong package: (myapppkg/myjavapkg). That is why I use setClassName.